# I'm currently logged in my web mail (mail.com). How do I check cookie/session expiration time?

Tags: email, session

As the title say,

I'm logged in the account but apparently mail.com has a bug for which the original password is not recognized at next logins (after the first one).

So I'm afraid to lose access to my account and I'd like to understand.

- If there is a cookie linked to my login (so I'll not be locked out, but the login is maintained on browser close)
- **What's the expiration time of the current session, in which case the session would be terminated even if I'm still logged-in without closing the browser.**?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: When the session or cookie expires is totally up to what mail.com set those values.  You might be able to find the cookie, it likely will contain encrypted info that will be of no use to you.

Comment: @Insane Chrome, latest stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Is) there is a cookie linked to my login

Probably. But mail.com ultimately has the answer.

> What's the expiration time of the current session?

1. Go to: **chrome://settings/cookies**
2. Search for your site, then click the cookie you want. You should then be able to see the details and **expiration** of that cookie (whether or not that's the cookie that stores your session, that's a different story)

Example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's difficult to know what cookie is used for login session. but Your answer has been useful, thanks